# Password manager for multiple computers?

Tags: security, sync, passwords, password-management

Is there a password manager that I can use on multiple computers, to remember all the passwords I use on the sites I visit?

Comment: I suggest you specify what operating system(s) you use.  Windows, OS X, Linux?

Comment: dupe? http://superuser.com/questions/255/how-do-you-keep-track-of-all-your-passwords

Comment: @fretje:  SU-Q255 didn't specifically ask about **multiple computers**.  So, I would say this is a more specialized version of the question and not strictly a dupe.  But, there's value in combining some of those answers with a sync tool or service.

Comment: And the most upvoted answer for KeePass on SU-Q255 specifically mentions cross-platform as one of the reasons the person answering (me! :)) uses it.

Answer (score 17):

If you are already using a password manager, you could combine that with a cloud service like dropbox, or mesh. Just make sure that you can save the profile of your password manager inside a folder that is synced by the cloud service and all your other connected computers will get the updates!

Comment: +1 for suggesting a local password manager (most secure) in conjunction with cloud storage.  Additional tip: Don't store your master password in the cloud :-)

Comment: I use the password file on Dropbox, but require a key file that is not on dropbox. Since the key file doesn't change, I don't have to worry about it being out of sync. But since the password file needs the keyfile to be opened, I'm covered if Dropbox gets hacked.

Comment: I'm using Keepass.

Comment: KeePass + mesh works fine for me as well ;)

Answer (score 17):

I have a very simple way of dealing with passwords:

I don't like password managers, but I like crypto, so I take advantage of one-way hashes (md5, sha1, etc) and generate passwords using them.

How it works?

First, I choose a good long password that I will use everywhere. For example qwerty (don’t use that, just an example). Now for every site, your password will be the md5 (or sha1) of qwerty + site name. For example:

```
$ echo “qwerty http://www.facebook.com” | md5
9d7d9b30592fd43dd6629ef5c12c6e9a

$ echo “qwerty http://www.twitter.com” | md5
cdf0e74e19836efb20f29120884b988d
```

That way my password for facebook is 9d7d9b30592fd43dd6629ef5c12c6e9a and for twitter is: cdf0e74e19836efb20f29120884b988d

Both long and secure. If someone steals my twitter password he has no way to reverse back to figure out the other passwords. Plus, doing that you don’t need any password software stored (just the md5/sha1 binaries which come by default on Linux and are easy to find on Windows).

Comment: Sounds pretty cumbersome - do you literally have to open up a shell and type that command to log in to any site?

Comment: That's actually nice, except for websites that trim the password to their criteria WITHOUT telling you but surprisingly they only trim on signup and not on login.

Comment: or use http://passwordmaker.org that is basically a GUI around that idea.

Comment: How do you remember what the *exact* site name is?  For example, http://www.facebook.com now directs to the secure login page (https://www.facebook.com  - not formatting right but that's https instead of http as the protocol).  Will you remember that when you created the password, you used the old nonsecure page?  Or what about when www.foo.com starts directing you (a year later) to www.foo.com/login or something like that?

Comment: In addition to password recall, you also have several other issues that prevent this from being a 100% solution. For instance, sites that have specific password requirements (symbol, upper-case, max-length, etc.) would all break this approach. Then you would have to remember which sites you hashed and which sites you had to set different passwords to, in addition to everything you already have to remember (password, hash key, site name, etc.).

Comment: AAARGH! Principle is fine, but your keyphrase will be all over your bash logs **AND** will be visible to other user of the machine you're on if you type it in like this!

Comment: @sucuri Interesting idea, but what do you do when a website forces you to replace your password every 3 months (and even checks that the new password is different than the old one)?

Answer (score 10):

[Lastpass](https://lastpass.com/) is another good alternative.

Comment: ...and the Lite version is free

Answer (score 6):

Something like Keepass on a USB drive that you always have available might be a workable solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend KeePass: [Keepass.info](http://keepass.info)

The latest version has built in sync option so you can setup a local ftp server or a network share and use keepass. Network share might be simpler as keepass implements its on file locking mechanism so it will tell you if someone else is using the password database. It also has many ports so you can even put it on ur mobiled phone, home computer (ftp sync), etc..

Comment: KeePass is available in binary form for most operating systems and some PDAs.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Password Safe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/), and manually sync the data file between the computers I use regularly (a handful -- it's manageable.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://passwordmaker.org/

The cool thing about this is that you don't need to synchronize passwords between multiple computers because given a master password and the name of a website it will generate a password for that site that will be the same every time from any computer.

There's a plugin for firefox, and various other tools to generate the passwords.

Answer (score 2):

[Keepass Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/keepass_portable) installed inside a [Dropbox](https://www.getdropbox.com/referrals/NTE1ODgwNjA5)* folder works really well. If you often use public computers, you can use [Dropbox Portable](http://forums.getdropbox.com/topic.php?id=7729&replies=6) to sync the passwords to your thumb drive.

There is also [Passwordmaker](http://passwordmaker.org/), but it only works for new passwords. If you don't want to bother to change all your old passwords, it good for you current accounts.

*Warning: refferal link

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? I do not personaly support doing this, but this is what you are looking for.

- http://www.passpack.com/en/home/
- http://www.clipperz.com/
- http://www.mysafebox.com/mysafebox/welcome.msb

I have not used these, but I recommend finding reviews and user experience stories as this could be a potential major security hazard.

Comment: Passpack is a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about passwords for websites, etc. then I recommend using the Firefox extension XMarks.  All you have to do is install it on every computer and it will synchronize passwords as well as bookmarks.

Comment: XMarks has plugins for IE, Friefox and Safari

Comment: Was a great option in '09 but XMarks is closing down at the end of '10.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Xmarks: The Easiest Way To Synchronize Bookmarks (Or Favorites)](http://www.technologyjuice.com/xmarks-the-easiest-way-to-synchronize-your-browsers/). It also synchronizes your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Roboform has an online capability, not only can you sync but my understanding is that you can access the stuff on their site without having the client installed (say, someone else's computer.)

They also have a U3 version of the program--put it on a U3 key and you can use it on any computer.

Answer (score 1):

Seconding [Clipperz](http://www.clipperz.com).  This is an excellent site that allows you to download a local copy of your passwords that can be opened by any javascript-capable browser, giving you offline access.  It also allows you to setup one-time-only passphrases to minimize exposure to keyloggers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox with [Firefox Sync](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/sync/) (also known as Weave) is good for that. Remote storage is encrypted; the encryption password is separate from your Weave credentials.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of great devices for password management (http://mylok.ii2p.com/ and Roboform) . I'm constantly traveling and I've found them more useful when I'm hopping from computer to computer.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [JPass](http://metis.freebase.hu/jpass.html). It is java-based simple application, so i can use that on Linux at home and Windows at work (and it is freeware for private and commercial use). Very handy app.

> JPass is a simple, small, portable, free and cross-platform password
>   manager application with strong encryption. It allows you to store
>   user names, passwords, URLs and generic notes in an encrypted file
>   protected by one master password.