# Cross platform centralized password manager

Tags: ssh, passwords, mysql

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Password manager for multiple computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/25132/password-manager-for-multiple-computers)
>   [Cross-platform centralized desktop password manager](https://superuser.com/questions/142631/cross-platform-centralized-desktop-password-manager)

Do any of you know a password manager, that would maybe look a bit like KeePass, but client/server. I wanna be able to simply install it on the user's computer and he's always up-to-date.

It is meant to manage ssh/ftp/mysql/http, so it would be nice to have an integrated launcher

Comment: Are you sure you're willing to store your credentials on someone else's server without knowing what that person might do with it?

Comment: How would KeePass with its database on the server fall short for you?

Answer (score 1):

KeePass, it's very popular and has versions for Windows, Linux, Mac, iPhone, Blackberry, etc, etc, etc.  Here's their download page http://keepass.info/download.html.

edit: to sync the keypass database between multiple computers you could use any of a multitude of file sync programs.  I would recommend drop box though, as it has worked for me with KeyPass.

Comment: It's called KeePass, not keypass.

Answer (score 1):

Plain text files stored in a TrueCrypt file, saved in a DropBox directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to flat text files, myself.  PGP/GPG encrypt them to the group who needs access if you can't trust their machines to keep it safe.

It doesn't get much more portable than text.

Answer (score 0):

[1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password) is very popular with the Mac-crowd.
The OSX, iPhone & iPad versions are very mature.
The windows version is currently in beta.

I have my keychain on my [dropbox](http://getdropbox.com/) and never had problems with sharing it.

On my linux box I use the fact that the keychain is just a zip file,
which actually provides html based access to your passwords.